# Switching Between Screens with React Native Navigation and importing JS

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, jsx, react-native-tabnavigator

I'm struggling to figure out why my code doesn't work. I keep reading the tutorials and nothing helps. How can I switch between screens and have the screens in different JS files (as components)?

Currently, my code works for the first screen, but when I click on the button nothing shows up.

Please see the codes below:

**App.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import TestScreen from './components/Test';


//HOME SCREEN
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Test"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Test',{myParam: '03',})}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Test" component={TestScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Test.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

class Test extends Component {
    render() {
   const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Test Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Test"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
        />
      </View>

    );
  }
}   


export default Test;
```

Comment: why do you wrap the stack inside <NavigationContainer> ? i could't see that in their demo https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/

Comment: @Anees see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/

Comment: Oh i see, can you try their demo as it is. I am sure we are missing something small :)

Comment: @Annes their demo doesn't show an example with the component in another file. If I add the component to the main (App.js) it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was a very simple issue and I figured it out myself. The code in Test.js was missing '**Button**' in the import statement. The correct way should be:

```
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";
```

It's a silly mistake, but it's not the first time this happens to me. I use Visual Studio Code, which highlights missing connections, but it seems that this doesn't work for some components. Not to mention it compiles (bundling) with no problems.

Nevertheless, the code works fine now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).